# Changing language for material tab items

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have an option of multiple languages support in my application by defining the multiple string files, where the user can switch to appropriate language as desired. Changing language take effect everywhere except on tab items and the toolbar above the TabLayout.Thanks

Here is the code of my XML file

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is how the tabs titles are being set

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), getResources().getString(R.string.general));
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), getResources().getString(R.string.crops));
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), getResources().getString(R.string.livestock));
        adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), getResources().getString(R.string.modern_technology));
        //adapter.addFrag(new FiveFragment(), "Pests");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: @A.Wahab yes, i did

Comment: Plz reason for -ve marking

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you should have a class that extends FragmentPagerAdaper. FragmentPagerAdapter class exposes a method called "getPageTitle" (more info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter#getPageTitle(int)). Override getPageTitle method and return the title you want. Code below

```java
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment currentFragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
            return currentFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.your_title_0);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.your_title_1);
                default:
                    return getString(R.string.your_title_default)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I posted the way I am setting the tabs titles that is technically not different than yours, but here comes the problem language change doesn't take effect. only the english titles stay there

Comment: It seems pretty weird to me, have you tried to log the result of getString() function in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired results by extending the TabsActivity with BaseActivity instead of AppCompatActivity

```
public class TabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

changed to

```
public class TabsActivity extends BaseActivity
```